# error callback of subscribe method is not firing in angular4

Tags: angular

I handled a bad request for login in the client which worked perfectly. But when I am trying to do the same for registration the error callback is not firing. Here is the code snippets :

```
Submit(){
this.userService.create(this.user).subscribe(x=>{
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
},
(error) => {
  console.log("heloo from error");
  this.message=error._body;
  this.invalidRegistration=true;
});
```

}
There is no message in the console while there is an error response. 
Here is the console:
[image: Browser console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, **`(err)`** needs to be outside the **x**

```
this.userService.create(this.user).subscribe((x) => {
   this.router.navigate(['/login']);
},
(err) => {console.log(err)});
```

To get the error msg back, add a catch that will return the error object:

```
create(user){
  return this.http.post('http:..../', user)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any) { 
  let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
  return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Comment: I meant the error callback is still not firing, anyway I am using this code in the service. create(ob:any){
    return this.http.post(this.url,ob).map(res=>res.json());
  }

Comment: also use HttpClient instead of Http

Comment: you mean you fixed it?

Comment: May be you are right, but in my case I had problem with the api. Fortunately I fixed that.